# .htaccess Rewrite Rules for subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I use codeigniter as my main install on the main domain. I have created a subdomain and a folder called live e.g. live.domain.com maps to public/live . However in public I use codeigniter.

I now have the dynamic codeigniter url:

```
http://domain.com/api/
```

which I want to map to my subdomain:

```
https://live.domain.com
```

So going to:

```
https://live.domain.com/api/functioname
```

would be using the script:

```
http://domain.com/api/apifunctioname
```

and possibly:

```
http://domain.com/api/apifunctioname/parameter1/parameter
```

Everything is on the same server so no redirects are needed.

Anyone have any ideas on which rewrite rules to use?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^live\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.+)$ "http://domain.com/api/$1" [L]
```

The above works great as a rewrite but redirects to http://domain.com/api/functionname instead I want it to route; so that when going to:

```
https://live.domain.com/api/functioname
```

It stays at that url but uses the script of

```
http://domain.com/api/functionname
```

Thank you very much,

Ice

Answer (score 10):

How about something like the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^live\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+)$ "https://domain.com/api/$1" [L,P]
```

Comment: Thank you however I tried that but I just got a 404 Not Found - very peculiar

Comment: I should probably mention that it is untested. Have you tried incresing the mod_rewrite loglevel, and analyzed what exactly is going on?

Comment: You should have "^live\.domain\.com" as the RewriteCond, and there should be a second RewriteCond checking for /api/ URLs.

Comment: I've been searching my server but cant find the log files anywhere; I've been looking for rewrite.log

Comment: Also when I set  RewriteLogLevel 3 in the .htaccess I get a 500 error

Comment: @Tomalak: Agreed, he should definitely do that.
@Ice: You can specify the log file with the RewriteLog-directive.

Comment: @jensen I tried that but receive a 500 error; also with some Twitter help I identified the rewrite problem; removing ^/ fixes it however I am not trying to rewrite the url but to map it on to it

Comment: Could you possibly post what you've ended up with so far?

Comment: Instead of [L] as flags to RewriteRule, try [L,P], iirc, that should perform a proxy request internally.

Comment: Thank you; however the change led to a 404 not found

Comment: Do you have mod_proxy enabled?

Comment: @jensen Brilliant! It had to enable mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http but yup then it worked! :D

Comment: I found it:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on

Answer (score 4):

Just add index.php, see below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^live\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+)$ "https://domain.com/index.php/api/$1" [L,P]
```