# .htaccess re-write rules for apache server, containing usernames as subdomains

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http, url-rewriting

I want .htaccess re-write rules for apache server, containing usernames as subdomains

For Example:

```
user1.xyz.com
to the following URL
user1.xyz.com/profile.php
```

If a straight request made by user then it will direct to

```
www.xyz.com
```

But if user isn't logged in then it shows that user profile as a visited user.

I have tried

[.htaccess Rewrite Rules for subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366586/htaccess-rewrite-rules-for-subdomain)

[htaccess Rewrite Rule for subdomain to page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976475/htaccess-rewrite-rule-for-subdomain-to-page)

Comment: Do you have wildcard domains setup? You will need them for this to work. After that I would suggest just mapping all subdomains that are not `www` to a single php script. In the php script you can check `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` to get the subdomain and perform a lookup.

Comment: Yes it is configured in panel to allow wildcard entries *.xyz.com
Now what are the mappings and rules?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, both links you provided show ways of doing redirects - which is only half of what you need because none of that handles validation of authorization.

I would redirect the user to the related links depending on his login status programmatically in PHP (since that's what you're using according to your tags). It's not hard to do a redirect in PHP according to what you're looking for...

Case 1: If user is logged in but not on the profile page, he will be directed to the profile page.

```
if($logged_in && !$user_is_on_profile_page)
{
    header('Location: http://user1.xyz.com');
    exit();
}
```

Case 2: If user is not logged but on the profile page, he will be directed to the homepage.

```
if($!logged_in && $user_is_on_profile_page)
{
    header('Location: http://www.xyz.com');
    exit();
}
```

That should get you going...